# Java WebSocketClient not receiving message of large size

Tags: java, android, websocket

I am using org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient to connect to a server from Android. Everything is working as expected, except when messages exceed a specific size. Does anyone know if you can increase the default maximum length?

```
WebSocketClient mWebsocketClient = new WebSocketClient(serverUri, new Draft_6455(), mHeaders, Constants.WEBSOCKET_CONFIG.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT) {

 @Override
 public void onOpen(ServerHandshake handshakeData) {
     Log.d(TAG, "Opened");
     mWebsocketClient.getConnection().
 }


 // Message does not come through if it exceeds a certain size
 @Override
 public void onMessage(String message) {
     Log.i(TAG, message);
 }

 @Override
 public void onClose(int code, String reason, boolean remote) {
     Log.i(TAG, String.format("Closed. Code: %s, Reason: %s, Remote: %s", code, reason, remote));
 }
 @Override
 public void onError(Exception ex) {
     Log.i(TAG, "Error " + ex.getMessage());
 }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I believe the default max is 4kb.

Comment: This should have been fixed by https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/pull/570, can you make sure you are using the latest version?

Comment: @TarunLalwani YES, it was indeed that! wow.. what a silly thing i did there, i was using an old version of the library. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should have been fixed by below pull request

https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/pull/570

Please make sure you are using the latest version